# Seeding QUASI_SCRAMBLED_SOBOL64 in CURAND

Tags: random, cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

How can I seed the `CURAND_RNG_QUASI_SCRAMBLED_SOBOL64` generator? Because it gives me the same numbers every time I run it and I can't use `curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed` with `CURAND_RNG_QUASI_SCRAMBLED_SOBOL64` to generate 64 bit random integers with `curandGenerateLongLong`.

How would I seed the generator in the following code?

```
size_t n = 10;
curandGenerator_t gen;
unsigned long long *devData, *hostData;

hostData = (unsigned long long *)calloc(n, sizeof(unsigned long long));

cudaMalloc(&devData, n*sizeof(unsigned long long));
curandCreateGenerator(&gen, curandRngType_t::CURAND_RNG_QUASI_SCRAMBLED_SOBOL64);

for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    curandGenerateLongLong(gen, devData, n);
    cudaMemcpy(hostData, devData, n * sizeof(unsigned long long), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%llx\n", hostData[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

curandDestroyGenerator(gen);
cudaFree(devData);
free(hostData);
```

Comment: Why can't you use curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed ?

Comment: Because `CURAND_RNG_QUASI_SCRAMBLED_SOBOL64` is not compatible with it and `curandGenerateLongLong` needs 64 bit generators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/group__HOST.html#group__HOST_1g56ff2b3cf7e28849f73a1e22022bcbfd), the quasi random generators, like the SOBOL generator you are using, don't use a seed. They use an offset and a dimension vector to initialise the generator.

So the initialisation sequence in your code should be something like

```
curandCreateGenerator(&gen, curandRngType_t::CURAND_RNG_QUASI_SCRAMBLED_SOBOL64);
curandSetGeneratorOffset (gen, std::time(0));
curandSetQuasiRandomGeneratorDimensions(gen, 10);
```